# permalink gem for mongoid (ActiveModel instead ActiveRecord)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, mongoid

I'm using Rails 3.1 and mongoid. I'm wondering if gem exists to make nice looking SEO url for certain model? (like friendly_id or permalink_fu) 
i would like to have urls like http://example.com/post/very_friendly_post (where **very_friendly_post** is title or another field of model)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard gem in use these days is https://github.com/digitalplaywright/mongoid-slug